# Wordpress | generate unique link

Tags: wordpress, custom-controls, dynamically-generated, personalization

I am turning to Stackoverflow community for a need of critical advice.

It's simple, I want a person to generate a link... and that link will have a button where whoever it is sent to, that person can click yes/no - then return the value.

user 1 > generate link > user 2 > options > return option to user 1

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do your users have roles in wordpress? Do they have to register and login?

Comment: Also - how do users contact each other - via wordpress, email or something different

Comment: Sorry I left that out...
Yes the users are both registered in wordpress and different roles ...

Comment: About contacting eachother, I was simply thinking of using a link - but I would love to have a history of the generated links and tracks each, but thats more complicated. I am looking just a simple trackable unique link to the author - perhaps even like a rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code you need is in wp-login.php

Generate unique URL (for password reset)

Email URL (or you could just display it)

Set user profile metadata (so you can track it)

If you want to track individual users, then you can either generate a unique url per user, per authored page or perhaps simpler is generate one unique url per page, but check that the user is logged when the unique link is clicked.

Either way you can use that to prevent multiple votes etc